# How to get character level difference using “difflib” command in Linux using python?

Tags: python, linux

I have two SQL files, one is old.sql and the other one is new.sql.

Suppose old.sql contains a table with three fields, Emp_Id, Name and Address and data stored in old.sql as follows:

```
Insert into table1 values (101 ,"a", "xyz");
Insert into table1 values (102 ,"b", "pqr");
```

Then I have changed "a" address "xyz" to "xyz123" and saved that data in the new.sql file. Now the new.sql file contains data as follows:

```
Insert into table1 values (101 ,"a", "xyz123");
Insert into table1 values (102 ,"b", "pqr");
```

When I use the difflib command like this:

```
difflib old.sql new.sql
```

it gives differences line-wise but I want only updated data, like `xyz123`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `diff` doesn't know what part of the line you define as "data" and what as "syntax". If you did a line-wise diff, you would get `123");` to be the part that is different.

```
Insert into table1 values (101 ,"a", "xyz");
Insert into table1 values (101 ,"a", "xyz123");
                                         123"); <-- difference
```

So you need to actually *parse* each different line, with a script that knows what to interpret as syntax and what to interpret as actual data.

Since your data files are big, you could open the two files at the same time in Python, and read in one line of each and compare it.

```
fh1 = open('file1.sql', 'r')
fh2 = open('file2.sql', 'r')

while True:
    line1 = fh1.readline() or break;
    line2 = fh2.readline() or break;
    check_difference(line1, line2)

close(fh1)
close(fh2)
```

Checking the detailed difference will depend on you file's syntax.

```
def check_difference(line1, line2):
    if line1 == line2: 
        return None

    # Get a list with the cleaned up data fields.
    data1 = get_values_list(line1)
    data2 = get_values_list(line2)

    # Compare each individual field.
    for i in range(len(data1)):
        if data1[i] != data2[i]:
            print('Difference: {} --> {}'.format(data1[i], data2[i]))

def get_values_list(s):
    # Split a line into data fields and remove quotes, etc.
    li = s[s.index('(') + 1 : s.index(')')].split(',')
    return [x.strip(' ').strip('"\'') for x in li]
```

That's untested, but basically that should do the comparison fine. It doesn't read in entire files, and returns only the individual data fields that changed.

Comment: but i need table name, column name  and data which has changed.

Comment: Please let me know if any command available in python which compare line word by word.